# Windows won't update, or install .NET framework, or run sfc /scannow

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework, c++

So, I've been trying a lot of things to get my computer to run a few programs that depend on C++ and the .NET framework. I tried to reinstall the .NET framework, but it failed, with the error message

> catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF)

Soon after, I realized that Windows was not updating at all; I tried a LOT to get it to update, but usually wound up with the same error code (`0x8007007e`).

I attempted a LOT of troubleshooting steps, but none of these seemed to help. My Windows Update log file is [here](https://share.rtechsupport.org/WindowsUpdate.log).

I've tried to run `sfc` in safemode, and manually enabled trustedinstaller, but it still did not work, giving me the same error. I've also tried running `DISM.exe`, it loads to 100%, then gives me a message that says an error occurred and no changes were made.

PS: I would like to avoid reinstalling windows or any hardware changes at all costs.

Comment: If you need to add or correct information in your question please [edit] it, do not post comments only.

Comment: Are you positive that the program requires both the Visual C++ Redistribution 20xx and .Net Framework?

Comment: I don't know, but there's still the issue of windows not updating and sfc or dism working.

Comment: And it is probably 2 different programs, one depending on .net, the other depending on c++.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows iso file just mount it and with the help of dism tool you can add .net framework without any errors.. just google on how to install windows features with an iso

Comment: That's not my only issue... windows won't update either.

Comment: What error code do you get for windows update. Is it same as mentioned earlier

Comment: Yes. 0x8007007e

Comment: I also had this error some days back with a cumulative update in windows. All i did was an implace upgrade as even microsoft chat support also wansnt helpful

Comment: How might I do this? Just a quick google search gives me an application to create an ISO to install windows. Wouldn't this destroy all of my files?

Comment: Also, the files I care the most about are my program files. So any method that destroys my program files is bad.

Comment: @MazeOfEncryption ya its bad but their is no other way because windows update went into a state where their download or install updates. So either u must reset the windows drive or u can use it without updates which is worthless. From my experience with the above same issue i had to start from scratch and it is now working fine